# How to delete spam comments on my youtube videos and block spammy channels from commenting on my videos?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Using YouTube API V3 I have successfully identified the spam comments on my channel. The problem is using the delete API costs 50 credits which is alot given daily 10K credits only.
YouTube studio provides no way of deleting comments by ID and if I go to Settings -> Community -> Hidden users and add the spammy users to the list according to YouTube it will take a lot of days for the past comments to get removed. What to do, please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try out https://github.com/ThioJoe/YT-Spammer-Purge. It is a tool that lets you filter and search for spammer comments on your channel and other's channel(s) in many different ways AND delete/report them all at once.

The tool has a [full wiki](https://github.com/ThioJoe/YT-Spammer-Purge/wiki) to help you with using it.

---

Here is the creators video showing it off:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-vOakOgYLUI

Here is an LTT video showing how it works:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zo_uoFI1WXM

Answer (score 1):

The 10k quota is for development use only YouTube expects you to request a quota extension if you need more quota then that.  Fill out the form and request more.

- [YouTube API Services - Audit and Quota Extension Form](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form)

Should take a couple of weeks to get approved.